# How to prepare an ionic app for production

Tags: ionic-framework

During my development of ionic app $http service in my app uses dev server ( http://localhost:3000 ) to make REST calls.

However production server is different. When i am building the app for different platforms I would like to use a different URL.

How does one set these variables dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use config to specify the base url for the REST calls (you might already be doing this), but instead of going

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http:localhost:3000/account.json'
  });
```

in one file and

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http:locahost:3000/user.json'
  });
```

in another file, create a constant that is injected into each service that requires the base URL.

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
  .constant('myConfig', {
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
```

So you can then use it like this in each service:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: myConfig.baseUrl + '/user.json'
});
```

What this means is that you only need to change that one `myConfig` file when you move between environments. However, it is still a manual task that you have to remember to always do. You can however go on and use [grunt-template](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/grunt-template) to automate the process.
Check out [this page](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/5) for more detail.

Comment: If you are currently using grunt-template as describe in the page I linked to, I might need more clarification on what you're after.